# Is it safe to throw moldy items away

Tags: mold, fungus

I have a lot of things which were covered in fungus. I have to go to some recycling area to throw them out. I want to know if is it safe as I heard fungus can get in your breathe.

What is the best way to dispose of items covered in fungus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toxins from fungi can definitely become airborne. When removing them, since you have a lot of items, use a N95 respirator just to play it safe. Place items in a large plastic bag and seal the bag before placing it in  your car. As a common courtesy, let the people at the recycling facility know about the fungi.

Comment: Couldn't put in the plastic bag as they were as big as bed headboard or frame. what would u have advice for that? I opened up all windows on the car and full fan to keep it vented as I am asthmatic.

Comment: You could wrap up the items up in plastic drop cloths.  Home stores sell big sheets of plastic to protect floors when painting, etc.  You could also transport the items in an open back truck.  Sounds like you did take precautions in driving though.  You want to be extra careful because of the asthma.

Comment: thanks, do my car need washing, those things were in the boot(trunk) so we also bring groceries in the car. any special treatment?

Comment: You should be fine.  You can spray a lite mist of vinegar in the truck to kill off any mold that might have fallen of the items.

Answer (score 0):

This equipment (water bottle cut open, hose and hairdryer) is giving protection also in case of putting parts covered with fungi into plastic bags:
[https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/182964/how-to-keep-the-dust-down-when-sawing-indoors-in-the-dead-of-winter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkuu2.jpg)